# api.ai losing conversation context - signalr

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr, signalr-hub, dialogflow-es

I'm currently working on .net mvc 5 application where i want to add integration for my agent made with Api.ai. I"m using SignalR too to ensure async communication between client and server. the problem is, i keep loosing the context of the conversation and the parameters are lost and the bot keeps asking for them.

**code for my SignalR hub:**

```
public class SupportHub : Hub
    {
        ApiAiUtility ai = new ApiAiUtility();
        public void Send(string message)
        {
            var response = ai.Ai.TextRequest(message);

            if (response.Result.GetStringParameter("subject") != "" &&
                response.Result.GetStringParameter("description") != "")
            {
                //TODO: Add code to handle adding the ticket to database

            }
            Clients.All.echoBack(response.Result.Contexts);

        }
```

I'm suspencting that the hub is not keeping the connexion with the Api.ai.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by changing this line:

```
ApiAiUtility ai = new ApiAiUtility();
```

to this:

```
static ApiAiUtility ai = new ApiAiUtility();
```